# Checkbox state not changed on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, postback

I have the following mark up for a User Control (.ascx)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Logical Symbol to Search:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlComponentType" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlComponentType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdvSearchAllLibs" runat="server" ToolTip="Check this box to search all available libraries" Text="Search All Libraries"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Search by Logical Symbol Properties:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On page Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SearchResults(ref attributeSearch, compTypeID);
}
```

where SearchResults is

```
 private void SearchResults(ref string attributeSearch, int compTypeID)
    {
        DataTable dtResults = this.AdvancedSearchControl.GetSearchResults(ref attributeSearch, compTypeID);
    }
```

And in my UserControl.ascx.cs

```
public DataTable GetSearchResults(ref string _attrVals, int compTypeID)
{
                //Other Logic Goes Here
                IEnumerable<Model.ComponentInfo.ComponentType> compTypeResult = from compTypes in BLLibrary.GetComponentTypeBasedOnLib(this.CurrentLibraryId, this.CurrentLibrary, this.chkAdvSearchAllLibs.Checked) select compTypes.Value;
}
```

`this.chkAdvSearchAllLibs.Checked` is always false no matter if the `check-box` is checked on page and posted back or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Server side:**

Add AutoPostBack="True" to the CheckBox. It's not posting back.

**Client side:**

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" onclick="checkboxchanged(this);" />

function checkboxchanged( sender ) {
if ( sender.checked ) {
        // clicked and checked
    } else {
        // clicked and unchecked
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna reload the page everytime the state of checkbox changes, thus I didn't set that prop. But the way it is right now is supposed to work. what am I missing here??:(

Comment: Put it in an update panel if you don't want the entire page to post back.
You cannot fire an event without postback.

Comment: Correct,I know UpdatePanel is an option(basically a work around). I am checking the checkbox state on Postback where Checkbox is expected to have its state right. Even UpdatePanel posts back except with no page reload(ajax) My question is why is it not working at the first place.and I want to lean what am I missing.

Comment: So you don't want the checkbox to fire the command, you want the DDL to check the checkbox state on it's selectedindexchanged event. Correct?

Comment: Yes and Basically in the ascx.cs file I have a logic based on the checked/Unchecked value of the checkbox.where `this.MyUserControl.chkAdvSearchAllLibs.Checked` is returning false always

Comment: Add the event that is supposed to check the checkbox checked status to your question.

Comment: Pls Check the Updated Ques